# Android: Make a background out of two elements

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background

This question is probably really simple, but I didn't really know what to search for and therefore I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

I want to make a background for my app's main screen. The background has to consist of just one color and in the lower right corner, I want a png-image of which I specifi the height and width.

How do you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 9 patch image. Make a small colored border on the top/left sides of your image, and make that border stretchable.

For example, in this image:

[image: test 9 patch]

The heart is your stationary image. The blue is the solid background color. The black pixels you see in the left/top corner define the stretch area, this tells it to stretch those blue pixels to fill the remaining area. It'a bit hard to see at this size, but if you save the image an look at it closer, you can see it better.

For more information on 9 patch in general, check the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). Just don't forget to change the file extension from `.png` to `.9.png` to make it work.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a try

Comment: Okay, it was a hell lot of work to understand the process and make a suitable pic. But after a lot of trial and error. IT WORKED! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Bitmap (from the code, because you need to specify width and height during runtime as I understood) which has a color in the background and another Bitmap in the corner.
2. Set this new Bitmap as a background for your View with `findViewById(R.id.layout_root).setBackgroundDrawable(yourComposedBitmap)`.

Comment: I don't need to specify width and height during runtime.

Comment: Could you provide a small example. I'm not familiar to using bitmaps

Comment: @Merlin If you don't need to specify width and height during runtime, can't you prepare an image in Gimp or other software, that has already a background and your picture in the corner? Then you can easily put such prepared image as a background, in XML.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but that stretches the image on screens with a different aspect ratio